# How can I incorporate sails into existing an express nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I have an existing express server setup and I would like to try incorporating sails into it to make use of the MVC structure it provides.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is a bit too broad of a question.  You'll need to post some details of your specific setup, and how exactly you'd like to incorporate Sails.